# pp_check for logistic regression in brms R package

Tags: r, regression, brms

I have fitted a multilevel logistic model with `brms` and afterwards ran `pp_check`. Can anyone help me interpreting the plot (what is on the horizontal/vertical axes, to start with)? Especially the curve labelled `y` is unclear to me, as the data are binary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.